# Passing variables into an Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I am trying to pass a variable into an Object so that the property's value is the variable I passed in.

```
var car = {
  make: 'Jeep',
  model: 'Renegade',
  year: yearVar
}

var yearVar = 2016;
console.log(car.year); //says year is undefined
```

So how do I set the property of the car Object equal to the yearVar variable?

Comment: There is no error. Have you tried swapping the positions of `var car = …` and `var yearVar = …`?

Comment: I left the console.log at the bottom and moved the declaration of the variable above the object and that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: So many answers for a simple problem of setting the value of the variable after using it. I feel so left out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined` is not an error. It's saying `undefined` because at the line you assign the value of `yearVar` to the object, the variable `yearVar` is not defined yet so it will assign `undefined` instead. (defining the variable afterwards won't solve the problem because `undefined` is already assigned). What you need to do is:

```
// define yearVar first
var yearVar = 2016;

var car = {
  make: 'Jeep',
  model: 'Renegade',
  year: yearVar // then use it afterwards (after it's been defined)
}
```

Comment: That was it, my order was messed up. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Declare variable `yearVar` and assign its value before you create `car` object.

```js
var yearVar = 2016;
var car = {
  make: 'Jeep',
  model: 'Renegade',
  year: yearVar
}
console.log(car.year)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to declare and set the yearVar varible before defining the car object. Javascript executes top to bottom Doing something like this would surely work

```
var yearVar = 2016;

var car = {
  make: 'Jeep',
  model: 'Renegade',
  year: yearVar
}

console.log(car.year);
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the problem is solved I am sharing something new but it is correct.    This is a technique used by the JavaScript engine called hoisting.

```js
yearVar = 2016; //check the var declaration in the bottom
var car = {
  make: 'Jeep',
  model: 'Renegade',
  year: yearVar
}

var yearVar;
console.log(car.year);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change after `car` has been created:

```
var car = {
  make: 'Jeep',
  model: 'Renegade',
  year:null
}

car.year = 2016;

console.log(car.year);
```